# php diamond with question mark after send mail

Tags: php

i have a php page that display exam (in Hebrew) and it display it correctly and in the bottom i have a send mail button of the exam to myself.

the problem its that after i send the mail to my self the mail its in hebrew But some of the letters i see "�" .

the charset its :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

and my header charset its also in UTF-8 ,i also try ISO-8859-1 but it give me the same.

the most strange thing its when i change the header charset to Big5 (chinese) i need to see in my email gibberish but  i see the same message

Comment: Needs more information! Show actual data and how it appears. Show how you send the message. Show the complete raw message, including email headers and all, as it is received.

Answer (score 0):

this is my Code:

```
$content = 
    writeExamDetails() .
    writeStudnetDetails() .
    writeAnswers($numOfQuestions);

    if ($_POST['studentComments']!=null) {
        $content .= "<p align=\"" . $text['align'] . "\"><strong>" . 
                    $text['studentComments'] .
                    ":</strong><br />" .
                    formatStr($_POST['studentComments']) . 
                    "</p>";
    }

    $body = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" >
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\" />
    <title>" . 
    $text['emailResultsPageTitle'] . 
    "</title>
    <style>
    body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    direction: " . $text['dir'] . ";
    text-align: " . $text['align'] . ";
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"color:#999999;\">
    If you cannot view the following contents properly, change the Encoding to Unicode (UTF-8).</p>" .
    $content;

    $body .= "<hr noshade=\"noshade\" height=\"1\" /><p>" . 
            $text['emailResultsDurationTitle'] . ": " . 
            duration((int)($_POST['lapsedTime']/1000)) .
            "</p>
            </body>
            </html>";

    $subject = "" . trim(stripslashes(stripslashes($_POST['examTitle'])));
                //formatStr2html($_POST['examTitle']);
    if (isset($_POST['studentId'])){
        $subject .= " (ID: " . $_POST['studentId'] . ")";
    }

    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\n" . $cc . 
                "Subject: " . $subject ."\n" .
                "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\n" .
                "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                "X-Priority: 1\n" . "Importance: High\n" . "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n" .
                "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";



    $result = mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

and this is how its look in HEBREW (i hope you understand hebrew)

in browser (its correctly)---> "אחת שתים בדיקה אחת שתים בדיקה"

in email (not correctly) ---> "אחת שת�ם בדיקה אחת שתים בדי�קה"